# ntile() function wrongly binning

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I Have the following dataframe :

```
test3=data.frame(uu=c(rep(10,5000),1))%>% 
  mutate(Quantile=ntile(uu,2))
> test3
# A tidytable: 5,001 x 2
      uu Quantile
   <dbl>    <int>
 1    10        1
 2    10        1
 3    10        1
 4    10        1
 5    10        1
 6    10        1
 7    10        1
 8    10        1
 9    10        1
10    10        1
```

What I want to do is to bin numerical variable thanks to the quantiles of my distribution.

Weirldy, I expect to get 2 groups here with only 1 observation in the first group, but here it's not the case :

```
> table(test3$Quantile)

   1    2  
  2501 2500
```

It means that the value "10" could be present in the first and the second group....
Why the function ntile() does not work here ? Is there a better option to get this quantile binning ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you read the [ntile webpage](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/ntile.html)? It explains all of this right in the first few paragraphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're trying to group by quantiles of your distribution, perhaps this works for you? `ntile` is not the right tool for this.

```r
test3 <- data.frame(uu = c(rep(10, 5000), 1)) %>%
  mutate(Quantile = findInterval(uu, quantile(uu, seq(0, 1, len = 2+1)), rightmost.closed = TRUE))
table(test3$Quantile)
#    1    2 
#    1 5000 

head(test3, 3)
#   uu Quantile
# 1 10        2
# 2 10        2
# 3 10        2
tail(test3, 3)
#      uu Quantile
# 4999 10        2
# 5000 10        2
# 5001  1        1
```

(I used `2+1` to show that you need its length to be one longer than the number of bins you want to create.)